# Отрисовка траекторий в matplotlib. Есть данные, нет ошибок, выдаёт пустой график

Tags: python, matplotlib

Не могу понять где косяк. 
Код:

```py
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']

for number_trajectory in range(number_of_files):
    for number_object in range(len(trajectories[number_trajectory])):
        ax1.plot(trajectories[number_trajectory][number_object].time, threshold_down_r[number_trajectory][number_object], "--", c=colors[number_trajectory])
```

В списке `trajectories` находятся вложенные списки с объектами классов. У каждого из них есть несколько характеристик (для примера - `time`). 
В списке `threshold_down_r`, также вложенные списки, каждый из которых выглядит примерно так (и в том, и в другом списке данных больше, но все вложенные списки по длине равны между собой, т.е. `len(trajectories[1]) == len(threshold_down_r[1])`):

```py
trajectories[number_trajectory].time = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5]

threshold_down_r[number_trajectory] = [1950.0, 1950.0005, 1950.002, 1950.0045, 1950.008, 1950.0125, 1950.018, 1950.0245, 1950.032, 1950.0405, 1950.05, 1950.0605, 1950.072, 1950.0845, 1950.098, 1950.1125, 1950.128, 1950.1445, 1950.162, 1950.1805]
```

При запуске вышеприведённого кода никаких ошибок не выдаёт, но при этом показывает окно с пустым графиком.

---

Upd.
Ради интереса изменила код, чтобы вторым списком, передавался список, а не объект:

```py
for number_trajectory in range(number_of_files):
    for number_object in range(len(trajectories[number_trajectory])):
        ax1.plot(trajectories[number_trajectory][number_object].time, threshold_down_r[number_trajectory], "--", c=colors[number_trajectory])
```

Стало ругаться на строку и выдавать такие ошибки:

> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1374, in plot
>       for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 303, in _grab_next_args
>       for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 281, in _plot_args
>       x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 223, in _xy_from_xy
>       raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
>
> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Comment: Опять 25!. plot принимает итерируемый объект, а вы ему по одному числу подсовываете постоянно. Заносите данные из цикла в списки и выводите их через plot одной командой.

Comment: Окей, допустим так, но есть 2 непонятных момента. 

1. Я могу вместо `threshold_down_r[number_trajectory][number_object]` закинуть сразу весь подмассив `threshold_down_r[number_trajectory]`, но как тогда быть с первыми значениями? Я же не могу для списка вызвать характеристику `time`? (`trajectories[number_trajectory].time`). Выдаёт ошибку, что у списка такой характеристики нет.

Comment: 2. До этого я закидывала данные по характеристикам объектов именно таким образом: `ax1.plot(trajectories[number_trajectory][number_object].time, trajectories[number_trajectory][number_object].r, ".", c=colors[number_trajectory])` и всё отрисовывалось верно. Я тогда не понимаю, почему в одном случае такие данные принимает, а в другом нет. Было подозрение что подмассивы (списки) разной длины, но нет - проверила, длина одна и та же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отрисовка была верная. Маркеров '--' было просто не видно на графике. При смене маркеров всё встало на свои места. Это странно, потому что до этого я рисовала этими же маркерами ('--') и они отображались нормально.

Comment: я уже во втором вопросе пытаюсь до вас донести одну вещь - лучше (эффективнее и функциональнее) отрисовывать график, передавая методам итерируемые объекты, а не рисовать по одной точке в цикле.

Answer (score 0):

Мне по вопросу трудно представить тип и размерность данных, передаваемых в отрисовку. я бы сделал как-то так:

```
X=[]
Y=[]
for number_trajectory in range(number_of_files):
    for number_object in range(len(trajectories[number_trajectory])):
        X.append(trajectories[number_trajectory][number_object].time)
        Y.append(threshold_down_r[number_trajectory][number_object])
```

а потом уже, вне цикла:

```
ax1.plot(X, Y, "--", c=colors[number_trajectory])
```

Плюс такого подхода еще в том, что вы всегда можете проверить после цикла X и Y, чтобы уточнить размерность и типы.

Comment: То есть работать со списком из объектов класса в matplotlib не получится? Нужно раскладывать каждую характеристику объекта в отдельный список? Я так делала изначально, но закрались подозрения, что это неправильный подход. Зачем создавать дополнительные переменные, если уже есть готовые данные.

Comment: Наоборот, надо работать со списками. а вы при каждой итерации цикла скармливаете matplotlib по одному числу.

Comment: Вы пытались внести правку в мой ответ. Лучше, внесите ее в свой вопрос ;)